# Web.config rewritemap

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I'm trying to do some rewrite rules for the homepage and individual pages for a current site to point people to a new site as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
                    <add key="/" value="http://www.domain2.co.uk" />
                    <add key="/contact-us/" value="http://www.domain2.co.uk/contact-us/" />
                </rewriteMap>
            </rewriteMaps>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The redirects don't seem to be doing anything though. :( Can someone tell me if the syntax i have is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you doing this with the URL Rewrite feature?  Honestly, trying to do it without that will just get you into trouble.